# Does $\frac{d}{dx}\limsup_{n \to \infty} \, ( f_n(x)-f_n(0))=\frac{d}{dx}\limsup_{n \to \infty} \, f_n(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, limsup-and-liminf

Let $f_n$ be a sequence of positive bounded functions and $g(x)$ be some positive bounded functions.

Suppose, we have an identity
\begin{align}
\limsup_{n \to \infty}  \, ( f_n(x)-f_n(0))=  g(x)-g(0)
\end{align}
for all $x$.

Now I want to take derivative of both sides with respect to $x$. 
Clearly, we have that 
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dx}\limsup_{n \to \infty}  \, ( f_n(x)-f_n(0))=   \frac{d}{dx}g(x)
\end{align}

**My question:** Is it true that 
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dx}\limsup_{n \to \infty}  \,  f_n(x)=   \frac{d}{dx}g(x)
\end{align}
For example, this is true if $f_n(0)$ is a constant for all $n$.  Is it true in general.   In other, words I am asking if
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dx}\limsup_{n \to \infty} \, ( f_n(x)-f_n(0))=\frac{d}{dx}\limsup_{n \to \infty} \, f_n(x)
\end{align}

My opinion is that no. Since, limsup's are subadditive and not additive that is, in general, we only have
\begin{align}
\limsup_n (a_n+b_n)  \le \limsup_n a_n +\limsup_n b_n.
\end{align}

Comment: I think you need uniform convergence of the family $\{f_n\}$ and it's derivability in order to do what you're saying.

Comment: Let $f_n(x) = 1+\exp(-|x|)$ for odd $n$ and $f_n(x) = 1$ for even $n$. Then $$\limsup_{n\to\infty}(f_n(x)-f_n(0)) = 0, \qquad \limsup_{n\to\infty}f_n(x) = 1+\exp(-|x|).$$